# Gremlin group all returned edges with its vertices

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I am a beginner in gremlin with Tinker pop. I have a graph where a cuisine has multiple `inE("serves")` from restaurants:
[image]

From these restaurants, I want only two restaurants which have location "Karachi".
These are:
[image]
[image]

For this, I've written the query and it works fine:

```
g.V(26).as("cui").inE("serves").outV().hasLabel("restaurant").has("location", "karachi").as("rest")
```

What I want is a gremlin query that gets the `inE("reviews")` of these restaurants and shape the data in this way.

```
[
"restaurant" : // info related to restaurant,
"reviews": [{array of reviews}]
]
```

I've tried this script:

```
 g.V(26).as("cui").inE("serves").outV().hasLabel("restaurant").has("location", "karachi").as("rest").where(__.inE("review").has("value",is(gte(2)))).inE("review").order().by("value", desc).as("rev").select("rest","rev").by(elementMap())
```

But it returns an array of data for every rating in this structure:

```
["rest": {}, "rating:" {}],
["rest": {}, "rating:" {}],


==>{rest={id=54, label=restaurant, name=restaurant5, location=karachi}, rev={id=67, label=review, IN={id=54, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=9, label=user}, upvotes=3, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:13:58 PKT 2021, downvotes=1, value=12}}
==>{rest={id=60, label=restaurant, name=restaurant7, location=karachi}, rev={id=69, label=review, IN={id=60, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=6, label=user}, upvotes=4, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:16:45 PKT 2021, downvotes=3, value=5}}
==>{rest={id=60, label=restaurant, name=restaurant7, location=karachi}, rev={id=71, label=review, IN={id=60, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=9, label=user}, upvotes=1, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:16:45 PKT 2021, downvotes=5, value=5}}
==>{rest={id=12, label=restaurant, name=restaurant1, location=karachi}, rev={id=41, label=review, IN={id=12, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=0, label=user}, upvotes=8, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 21:49:07 PKT 2021, downvotes=4, value=4}}
==>{rest={id=54, label=restaurant, name=restaurant5, location=karachi}, rev={id=65, label=review, IN={id=54, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=6, label=user}, upvotes=4, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:12:57 PKT 2021, downvotes=1, value=4}}
==>{rest={id=12, label=restaurant, name=restaurant1, location=karachi}, rev={id=40, label=review, IN={id=12, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=3, label=user}, upvotes=8, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 21:49:07 PKT 2021, downvotes=4, value=3.7}}
==>{rest={id=60, label=restaurant, name=restaurant7, location=karachi}, rev={id=70, label=review, IN={id=60, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=0, label=user}, upvotes=5, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:16:45 PKT 2021, downvotes=2, value=3}}
==>{rest={id=54, label=restaurant, name=restaurant5, location=karachi}, rev={id=68, label=review, IN={id=54, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=3, label=user}, upvotes=2, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:14:21 PKT 2021, downvotes=9, value=3}}
==>{rest={id=60, label=restaurant, name=restaurant7, location=karachi}, rev={id=72, label=review, IN={id=60, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=3, label=user}, upvotes=5, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:16:46 PKT 2021, downvotes=1, value=2}}
==>{rest={id=54, label=restaurant, name=restaurant5, location=karachi}, rev={id=66, label=review, IN={id=54, label=restaurant}, OUT={id=0, label=user}, upvotes=4.7, rated_at=Tue Nov 16 22:13:32 PKT 2021, downvotes=3, value=2}}
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at using the `project()` step (documentation [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#project-step)) to get this sort of information.  Without the steps to reproduce your graph, it is hard to give you the exact query, but it should look similar to the query below:

```
  g.V(26).as("cui").
  inE("serves").
  outV().
  hasLabel("restaurant").
  has("location", "karachi").
  project('restaurant', 'reviews').
    by(elementMap()).
    by(
      inE("review").
      has('value', gte(2)).
      order().by("value", desc).
      fold())
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is exactly what I wanted!!